# compiler flags on ARM based processors

Tags: linux, compilation, c++, arm, embedded-linux

I am compiling C++ source code on Nvidia Jetson nano. Some details of the processor are as follows:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 0                                            
model name      : ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l)                  
BogoMIPS        : 38.40                                        
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32   
CPU implementer : 0x41                                         
CPU architecture: 8                                            
CPU variant     : 0x1                                          
CPU part        : 0xd07                                        
CPU revision    : 1                                            

processor       : 1                                            
model name      : ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l)                  
BogoMIPS        : 38.40                                        
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32   
CPU implementer : 0x41                                         
CPU architecture: 8                                            
CPU variant     : 0x1                                          
CPU part        : 0xd07                                        
CPU revision    : 1                                            

processor       : 2                                            
model name      : ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l)                  
BogoMIPS        : 38.40                                        
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32   
CPU implementer : 0x41                                         
CPU architecture: 8                                            
CPU variant     : 0x1                                          
CPU part        : 0xd07                                        
CPU revision    : 1                                            

processor       : 3                                            
model name      : ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l)                  
BogoMIPS        : 38.40                                        
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32   
CPU implementer : 0x41                                         
CPU architecture: 8                                            
CPU variant     : 0x1                                          
CPU part        : 0xd07                                        
CPU revision    : 1
```

I get the following error when compiling the code;

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option _-mfpu=neon_
c++: error: unrecognized command line option _-mfpu=neon_
```

I want to know based on the above following specifications; what flags should I set for `mfpu`?

Comment: I think it depends which compiler you are using.

Comment: What compiler, compiler version, compiler options are you using when compiling what file? Please post minimal reproducible example. Also the flag `-mfpu=neon` is without underscores, not sure if that's formatting issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

For ARMv8-A profile processors the FPU and NEON are mandatory parts of the architecture (unlike ARMv7-A) so you shouldn't need a -mfpu flag to enable it.